# Why is the following for-loop for a running sum returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

was wondering why this for loop was returning undefined? Trying to return the running sum of the array.

```
var runningSum = function(nums) {
 let i  
  for (i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
  nums[i] + nums[i-1]
 }
 };
```

EDIT: I got rid of the `return` but it's still outputting undefined

Comment: This code will throw an error before it can be executed. `for` is a statement, and `return` expects an expression (something that evaluates to a value, eg: `1+2`, `true`) and not a statement to follow it.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense, but even without the return it's returning as undefined?

Comment: Yeah, you need to do something like `return <expression>;` at the end of your function, where `<expression>` is the thing you want to return. Otherwise you won't be returning anything, and so the default return value of `undefined` will returned instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental error is not returning the result from the function.

But also you must understand that `nums` is an array and **passed by reference** and therefore the function is modifying the input argument, in which case the return value might not actually be needed/intended.

Consider the following which prints both the return value AND the original input after the function call.

```js
const runningSum = function(nums) {
  for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    nums[i] += nums[i-1]
   }
   return nums
 }
 
 
const input = [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]

console.log(runningSum(input))
console.log(input)
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thank you so much! Also was wondering, why does it give the proper running sum only when using += and not just +. With just + aren't we still adding the previous number to the current number for each number starting at index 1?

Comment: Yes but you aren’t assigning it, so it’s discarded. e.g. A literal `1 + 1` is a valid statement but has no assignment.